# Easiest way to install GStreamer on Debian?

Tags: debian

I'm trying to get GStreamer 1.2 installed on my version of Debian (armel) that came with the board. It doesn't come with GStreamer. 
I installed the Debian image on my SOC following these instructions http://compulab.co.il/workspace/mediawiki/index.php5/CM-FX6:_Linux:_Getting_started

I'm really not too sure how to install GStreamer, and my workplace doesn't allow internet access. Has anyone done this before and can advise? Running short on time...

Thank you very much.

Comment: what's the problem with `sudo apt-get gstreamer1.0-plugins-*`?

Comment: I'm not allowed to access internet at my workplace. But realised that you can point apt-get to point to dvd instead. Does the apt-get gstreamer1.0-plugins-* install what I need to call say "gst-launch" command? Sorry quite noob to linux..

Comment: @Braiam I did apt-get install gstreamer0.1-plugins-* and the libraries are installed after some effort sorting out the dependencies. All I see are the libraries are installed in /usr/lib How do I get to the point where I can simply call gst-launch <something>

Comment: Nevermind apparently I had to apt-get install gstreamer0.1-tools as well...

Answer (score 3):

The following two command lines worked for me. They are inspired from the comments. There was a typo in Braiam's comment. I fixed it below:

Command 1

```
apt-get install gstreamer1.0-plugins-*
```

Command 2

```
apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-*
```

For those not familiar with those two packages they are actually metapackages. Meaning they will install multiple packages and offer you to install all their respective dependencies.

For advanced users interesting in the information source and general background about those two metapackages there is a related documentation for Debian in that documentation and its sub-pages at https://wiki.debian.org/MultimediaCodecs#Codec_Installations

Comment: Installing GStreamer 1.x should be sufficient as version 0.10 is no longer maintained and thus not recommended: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/frequently-asked-questions/getting.html?gi-language=c#what-is-the-difference-between-versions-010-and-10